# broadcast multiple 2d arrays as individual elements of another 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch, array-broadcasting

lets say I have 10 arrays of size 10x10 each, called a,b,c...j

I create np.zeros of 10x2 called arr. I've already made `arr[:,1]=1,2,3...10`

so as of now my new array is

```
[0,1]
[0,2]
...
[0,10]
```

What i need now is to make

```
arr[0,0] = a, arr[1,0] = b ... arr[10,0]=j
```

Since Im also dealing tensors, the error I get is

> "only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars"

Basically, to reiterate, I want to put those 2D arrays into my new array as individual elements of the new array.

Final output reqd:

```
[a,1]
[b,2]
...
[j,10]
```

EDIT: The final array will be multidimensional, but Im not sure of the value of the final shape, 10x10x2 maybe??

EDIT: Think of the problem as images and labels. I want to store an entire image and its corresponding label as each row of an array

Comment: What's the dtype of the new array?  What's the intended shape?

Comment: float32 or 64 whichever, im not sure what the value of shape will be, but for eg, arr[0,0] will be the entire array 'a', and arr[0,1] is 1

Comment: it'll become a multidimensional array essentially

Comment: Can't you create a multidimensional array of the right shape, and assign your 2d arrays to the appropriate slices?  Don't think in terms of assigning arrays to elements of another array.  Build on what you are already doing, e.g. `arr[:,1]=1,2,3...10`.

Comment: yeah, i thought of that, but like i said im not sure what the value of shape is, so i cant create an empty array of the reqd shape.

Comment: think of it as images and labels, I want to store an image and its corresponding label as each row of an array

Comment: Typically when you need to create a large array iteratively, we encourage you to use list append to make a list of lists (or arrays) and create the array with one call at the end.

Comment: I think you should have a `10x10x10` tensor for images and `10x1` for the labels. But why do you need to combine them into one tensor?

Comment: @wasi 1x10x10 coz grayscale, or 3 for RGB, either way, I still want to combine them to one big array. I'm tryna combine coz I need to shuffle, so  I need to keep track of labels and images together. I cant shuffle them individually.